# Change value of an input based on the original one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you copy an hidden input value attribute, manipulate it and then change it with a click function? To be more precise:

This:

```
<input type="hidden" id="destination" value="/change1/change2/fixed-part" />
```

To this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="destination" value="/changedtext/fixed-part" />
```

I've made some process but couldn't get the desired result. So far I get the value, manipulate it (not sure if it works alright) but couldn't replace it with the original one.

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ry4cc79/1/

Comment: `$('#destination').val(function() { return this.value.replace('change1/change2', 'changedtext') })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
document.getElementById('destination').value = "/changedtext/fixed-part";
```

Comment: This is very simple and works great! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#destination').val(function() { 
          return this.value.replace('change1', 'changedtext') 
    });
  alert("Changed Value:"+$('#destination').val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="destination" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/change1/change2/fixed-part" />
Try this should work,

<input type="hidden" id="destination2" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/changedtext/fixed-part" />

<button>Click to change the value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the hidden element
let el = document.getElementById('destination');
// Add the new val you want to minipulate the hidden elemets value with
let newVal = 'changedtext';

// then at a later state, you click the button
this.clickToChange = function () {
  // and voila, the value is replaced on the hidden element
    el.value = el.value.replace('change1/change2', newVal);
}
```